# SQL Buddy alternative for oracle

Tags: database, oracle, web-applications, admin

I'm looking for oracle admin tool like SQL Buddy ([here](http://www.sqlbuddy.com/)). I just want to use the browser to test my querys.

Answer (score 0):

For just to test querys you can try iSQL (but it is deprecated in 11g)
or may be look to http://www.oracletool.com/

Answer (score 0):

You could try using [APEX](http://apex.oracle.com). It isn't specifically an admin tool (more for power-users/developers), but it is built-in on newer databases. You can write SQLs, build packages and procedures, view and filter data, etc.

Answer (score 0):

While not web based I would suggest Oracle's (free) Sql Developer http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/downloads/index.html
or (also free/OSS) Squirrel:
http://squirrel-sql.sourceforge.net/

Comment: i'm currently using both - sqldeveloper and squirrel :) but I'M not happy with them...

Answer (score 0):

The best for me is SQLTool (http://www.sqltools.net/), it´s free, faster, easy to use and has a lot of option.

Answer (score 0):

Although they're not web-based, I like [toad](http://www.quest.com/landing/default.aspx?id=1485&s_kwcid=TC|18353|oracle%20toad||S|e|3872564839&gclid=CIP-1K-_-qUCFU0w3godjg5nmw) and [sqldeveloper](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/overview/index.html). The former is commercial software, but very good - the latter is currently free (but long-term....?).